Angular: scrollIntoView not working on route change without setTimeout in ngAfterViewInit
I have an Angular component where I want to use scrollIntoView when the route changes. Here's the relevant code snippet from my component:
@ViewChild('structure') structure: ElementRef | undefined;
legacyRoute: string = '';

constructor(private apiService: ApiService, private router: ActivatedRoute, private route: Router, private cdRef: ChangeDetectorRef) { }


ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.router.paramMap.subscribe(params => {
    this.legacyRoute = params.get('id') || '';
    console.log("checking legacy after param map subscription", this.legacyRoute);
    setTimeout(() => { 
      if (this.legacyRoute && this.structure && this.structure.nativeElement) {
        console.log("Running scrollIntoView", this.legacyRoute, this.structure, this.structure.nativeElement);
        this.structure.nativeElement.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth', block: 'start', inline: 'start' });
      }
    }, 1000)    
  });
}

Problem:
The scrollIntoView function works correctly on page refresh, but not when Angular routes change. I've added a setTimeout to delay the function, which makes it work, but I understand this is not a robust solution.
What I've tried:

Removing the setTimeout results in scrollIntoView not functioning properly on route changes.

Ensuring that this.structure.nativeElement is valid before calling scrollIntoView.

Using  ngAfterViewChecked() instead of ngAfterViewInit()


Expected Behavior:
I expect scrollIntoView to execute correctly when navigating to a different route within the Angular application, without relying on a setTimeout.
Additional Context:

Angular version:

  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^17.3.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^17.3.9",
    "@angular/common": "^17.3.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^17.3.0",
    "@angular/core": "^17.3.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^17.3.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^17.3.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^17.3.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^17.3.0",
    "@angular/router": "^17.3.0",
    "@angular/ssr": "^17.3.7",
    "@ngrx/store": "^17.2.0",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "force": "^0.0.3",
    "primeicons": "^7.0.0",
    "primeng": "^17.17.0",
    "rxjs": "~7.8.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.14.3"
  }


structure is a ViewChild or ElementRef pointing to the DOM element where scrollIntoView should be applied.
<-- something like <div #structure  id="structure">  -->


    My title

Since I'm new to Angular, I want to ensure I haven't overlooked anything important. Your assistance means a lot to me, and I sincerely appreciate your time and help. Thank you in advance!

Maybe you can try to listen on router navigation ends event to ensure navigation has been completed together with an effect for signals.
this should also works for initial call. I would try something like this.
private readonly navigationEnd = toSignal(
  this.router.events.pipe(filter((event): event is NavigationEnd => event instanceof NavigationEnd))
)

private readonly structure = viewChild('structur')

constructor() {
  effect(() => {
    // maybe called 2 times if navigation has been ended
    // and if structure has been resolved
    const navigationEnd = this.navitationEnd();
    const structure = this.structure();

    // scroll into view
  })
}

